# How to set background color to image map area

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have multiple pages with an image map. Every area redirects to a page with the same image map but different images on the side, I want to set the background color red to the current clicked block, how to do that? I have set hover color and the border with mapper.js but how to set the background color to stay on the active clicked area?

Comment: Can you share what you have tried?

Answer (score -1):

Add background-color to your existing css like so:

```
.active-floar-number {
    border: 3px solid #A77E4D;
    border-radius: 100px;
    padding: 0 25px;
    background-color: red; /* line 45 */
}
```